# Insert Mosquitto Message into dataGridView

Tags: c#, mosquitto, messagebroker

Hello I have an app that sends messages with values from one sensor to another app in C # through Mosquitto Broker.
I have 3 topics "topicTemperature, topicHumidity and topicBatery" for each topic, the message is a string with "sensorID SensorValue Date" I have a dataGridView with the following columns "ID, Temperature, Humidity, Batteries, and Date".
Message Examples:

```
"2 22.3 04/12/2019"  //TopicTemperature
"2 47.9 04/12/2019"  //TopicHumidity
"2 99 04/12/2019"  //TopicBatery
```

i have this code:

```
    string[] data;
    if (String.Equals(e.Topic, "topicTemperature")){
        data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message).Split(null);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(data[0], data[1]);
    }

   if (String.Equals(e.Topic, "topicHumidity")){
       data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message).Split(null);
       dataGridView1.Rows.Add(data[1]);
   }

   if (String.Equals(e.Topic, "topicBatery")){
      data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message).Split(null);
      dataGridView1.Rows.Add(data[1], data[2]);
   }
```

This is the output:

[image]

I Want this output:

[image]

What changes do I need to make for this to work?

**EDIT: Output with Jacobs code**
[image]

Comment: Will the 3 messages always come in a particular order?

Comment: in the same order as the Message Examples:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is your best option would be to create the row first, then add your values. This way you can control which column each piece of data gets inserted into.

EDIT: The code below gave me the output of the picture below. I had to use the input you gave me because I don't have sensors, but this should be the same concept you need.

```
        int rowNum = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

        string temp = "2 22.3 04/12/2019";
        string humid = "2 47.9 04/12/2019";
        string batery = "2 99 04/12/2019";

        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowNum];

        string[] data;
        if (String.Equals(temp,temp))
        {
            data = temp.Split(null);
            row.Cells["SensorID"].Value = data[0];
            row.Cells["Temperature"].Value = data[1];
        }

        if (String.Equals(humid, humid))
        {
            data = humid.Split(null);
            row.Cells["Humidity"].Value = data[1];
        }

        if (String.Equals(batery, batery))
        {
            data = batery.Split(null);
            row.Cells["Batery"].Value = data[1];
            row.Cells["Date"].Value = data[2];
        }
```

You will need to loop the creation of the rows but this should give an idea.

[image: Output]

Comment: I tried this and the output is  [link](http://shorturl.at/ITV27)

Comment: The link does not go anywhere.

Comment: The output is:
In first row i have only the value of ID and Temperature;
In second row its all blank;
In third row i have only the value of humidity;
And in the fourth row i have only the value of date;

Comment: I have your output with your code but when i change the if to if (String.Equals(e.Topic, "topicTemperature")) the output still one row per sensor look at the print in EDIT

Comment: I guess I am a little confused because if the only thing you are changing is the if statement variables then it shouldn't have an effect on the rows. Could you post a larger chunk of your current code block?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are declaring rowNum and row after you are invoking the method. You are creating a new row every time the sensor reads in data. Try moving the lines   int rowNum = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(); and DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowNum]; to before this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate  and see what happens.

Comment: if i change i have the following error: "System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203783/discussion-between-jacob-and-rodrigues).

Comment: Move the rows back and change the lineDataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowNum]; to DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[1]; and let me know what happens